# sqlite3 error: "Unable to resolve table" even though I already remade the table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have searched extensively before asking this seemingly simple question. I have a python project, made a sqlite DB and some code to insert and work with it, and all was good until I decided to pull the db functions out of the main file, and pull out the db file, and put both into a folder called db. So now both the function file and the db are in the same folder, one level deep. So the error starts immediately, but the code still runs, albeit not actually doing anything, I search the internet and all I see are people saying to delete the DB file, make it again in place and that usually solves the issue, I did that twice but no luck. What am I missing here? The code runs without an error, but does not actually work, and the error I am reporting here is from the pycharm hover box.

```
def add_symbols_to_list(symbols_to_add) -> None:
    """This will add symbols to the current symbols list, but leave the previous entries.
    :param: a list of user provided symbols as comma separated strings."""
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()  # get current time for the int conversion below
    this_month_int = time_now.month  # get the current month and set it to an int

    # gets the current number of rows so new additions have the correct rowid
    # c.execute("SELECT * FROM currentMonthStocks")
    # current_row_number = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM currentMonthStocks")
    # rows = int(current_row_number)
    # # https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-count-function/
    # db_row_id = rows + 1  # set the first row number

    extra_symbols = symbols_to_add

    for i in range(len(extra_symbols)):
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO currentMonthStocks
                   (symbol, month)
                   VALUES (?, ?)""", (extra_symbols[i], this_month_int))
        # db_row_id += 1
        print("Added a symbol")
    print("Symbols successfully populated into currentMonthStocks table in database.db")


new_symbols = ['tsla', 'dis', 'pltr']
add_symbols_to_list(new_symbols)


def get_symbols_at_month_start() -> None:
    """Function inserts a list of symbols to trade every month into the currentMonthStocks table in database.db.
    This is called once at the start of the month, deletes the current symbols and adds the new ones.
    :return: None."""

# edited out the url info for brevity    
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    symbols = response.json()['content']['allInstrumentRows']
    this_months_symbols = []

    for symbol in symbols:
        this_months_symbols.append(symbol['Symbol'])
    # print(this_months_symbols)

    # file = "database.db"
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')  # setup database connection
        c = conn.cursor()
        print("Database Connected")

        # c.execute("""CREATE TABLE currentMonthStocks (
        #             id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        #             symbol TEXT,
        #             month INT)""")
        # print("table created successfully")

        # # checks to see if there is at least 1 row in the db, if yes it deletes all rows.
        if c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM currentMonthStocks WHERE id=1 LIMIT 2);"):
            # for i in range(len(this_months_symbols)):
            c.execute("DELETE FROM currentMonthStocks")
            print("Delete all rows successful")

        time_now = datetime.datetime.now()  # get current time for the int conversion below
        this_month_int = time_now.month  # get the current month and set it to an int
        db_row_id = 1  # set the first row number

        for i in range(len(this_months_symbols)):
            c.execute("""INSERT INTO currentMonthStocks
                       (id, symbol, month)
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (db_row_id, this_months_symbols[i], this_month_int))
            db_row_id += 1
            # print("one more entry")
        print("Symbols successfully populated into currentMonthStocks table in database.db")

        conn.commit()  # commits the current transaction.
        print("Entries committed to database.db")
        # c.close()  # closes the connection to the db.
        conn.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("sqlite3 error", e)

    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
            print("Database.db Closed")
```

Comment: I tried to make the table again, and it says "sqlite3 error table currentMonthStocks already exists" but in another function in the same file, pointing to the same db filename, it is still giving the original error. I'm baffled :(

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem, or at least no solution, pycharm is still not recognizing the table but I wrote 5 CRUD functions and they all work. So the answer is don't worry about it, just see if the DB is updating correctly.